# Interchange of limit and sum justification

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

From the book I have been reading, it seems the following result is implicitly used:

If $f_{a}(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} s_{n}(a,x)$ converges uniformly with respect to (large) $a$, for example $\forall |x|<|a|$, and $\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} s_{n}(a,x) = s_{n}(x)$ $\forall n$ then,
\begin{eqnarray} \lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} s_{n}(a,x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} s_{n}(x). \end{eqnarray}
I have not been able to find a reference for such a Theorem that justifies this kind of interchange with limit and sum and I could not think of a proof. Is there a Theorem known for this? Or, any idea how to prove the result?

Of course, the result does seem very reasonable. Especially in the example I am working with (I haven't written it to minimise details and keep focus on the main part of my problem).

Many thanks for all help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is not true without extra assumptions.
If $X= \{ x\}$, then the result would state that we can interchange limits and integration whenever the limit of the integrals exists, which is simply not true.
However, even for arbitrary $X$, it is still not true. Let us define
\begin{align*}
s_n(a,x) = \begin{cases}  0 & a \not\in (n-1 , n] \\ 1 & a \in (n-1,n] \end{cases}.
\end{align*}
Then we have
\begin{align*}
f_a(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n(a,x) = s_{\lceil a \rceil }(a,x) = 1 
\end{align*}
for all $a$. So in particular $f_a(x)$ converges uniformly to $1$. However
\begin{align*}
s_n(x) = \lim_{a \to \infty } s_n(a,x) = \lim_{ \substack{a \to \infty  \\ a > n}} s_n(a,x) =0
\end{align*}
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Thus we find
\begin{align*}
1 = \lim_{a \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n(a,x) \neq \sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n(x) = 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Okay, thanks for the example. I'll be more specific, I'm looking at the example $s_{n}(a,x) = \frac{(a)_{n}(b)_{n}}{(c_{n})n!}\frac{x^{n}}{a^{n}}$ (this is the hypergeometric $\ _{2}F_{1}$ series with variable $\frac{x}{a}$). The book says, show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} s_{n}(a,x)$ converges uniformly with respect to $a \in [2|x| , \infty]$ (easy, this isn't my problem) and hence deduce that $\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_{n}(b)_{n}}{(c)_{n}n!}\frac{x^{n}}{a^{n}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(b)_{n}x^{n}}{(c)_{n}n!}$. But whats the justification for interchange here?

Comment: @analytic If $b,c,x$ are all positive, $\frac{(a)_n}{a^n}$ is increasing for all $a >0$, and thus you can use the Monotone convergence theorem. 
If $b,c,x$ are not all positive, you can cut your function in a positive $f_+$ and negative $f_-$ part, and then Mononotone convergence theorem on $f_+$ and $- f_-$, and then if everything is still finite, use linearity. But you should check to see if this is true, as I didn't know the hypergeometric series till now :).

Comment: Thank you very much. I had hoped that uniform convergence of the series was simply enough (as suggested in how the book is written), I will check these things you say.